# what are the similarity measure use for both continuous and categorical data?

Tags: machine-learning, search

I have searched but found that some similarity measures are for continuous data and some are for categorical data. But i want to know the similarity measures which are use for both data, continuous and categorical?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes continuous data can be represented as parametric distribution with distribution parameters as variable, essentially continuous stochastic process. In that case cross-entropy would work on that type of continuous data.